# Constructor template argument deduction with std::function as parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class with a template constructor like the following:

```
class Foo {
private:

    std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::vector<std::function<void(BaseT*)>>> funcs;

public:

    template<class T> Foo(const std::function<void(T* arg)>& func) {
        auto funcToStore = [func](BaseT* a) { func(static_cast<T*>(a)); };
        this->funcs[std::type_index(typeid(T))].push_back(funcToStore);
    }

}
```

This classes' constructor takes a function parameter with an argument of a type `T` derived from some base type `BaseT` and stores this function in a map of vectors utilizing `std::type_info` of `T` for the key.

As this is a template *constructor* and not an ordinary function, explicitly specifying the template parameter won't work, because this is no allowed syntax:

```
Foo* foo = new Foo<MyT>([](MyT* arg) { ... });
```

Omitting the explicit `<MyT>` also won't work because the template parameter can't be deduced from the lambda argument type.

So one solution would be to wrap the lambda in a `std::function` object:

```
Foo* foo = new Foo(std::function<void(MyT*)>([](MyT* arg) { ... }));
```

But this is obviously not a nice readable syntax.

The best I've come up so far is making use of an *alias* for the `std::function`:

```
template<class T> using Func = std::function<void(T*)>;

Foo* foo = new Foo(Func<MyT>([](MyT* arg) { ... }));
```

This is shorter, and when using the `auto` keyword in the lambda argument I would have to specify the actual type `MyT` only once, so this seems to be a nice solution in the end.

But can there be any other, even shorter solution? So that it wouldn't be necessary to wrap the lambda? Like:

```
Foo* foo = new Foo([](MyT* arg) { ... });
```

Comment: @StoryTeller: Good point, I updated the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a normal template parameter instead of `std::function`:

```
class Foo {
    std::unordered_map<size_t, std::vector<BaseT*>> funcs;

public:
    template<class T> Foo(const T& func) {
        // ...
    }

};
```

Now deduction will happen correctly, and your code won't suffer from the overhead of `std::function`.

What if you want to obtain the type of the first parameter of the lambda?

You'd have to make something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct function_traits : function_traits<&T::operator()> {};

template<typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<R(C::*)(Args...) const> {
    using arguments = std::tuple<Args...>;
    using result = R;
};
```

Of course, if you want to support every possible cases of function types, you need the [32 specialisations](https://github.com/gracicot/kangaru/blob/master/include/kangaru/detail/function_traits.hpp)

Now, you can extract the arguments types and even the return type if needed:

```
template<class T> Foo(const T& func) {
    using Arg = std::tuple_element_t<0, typename  function_traits<T>::arguments>;
    auto funcToStore = [func](BaseT* a) { func(static_cast<Arg>(a)); };

    funcs[typeid(Arg).hash_code()].push_back(funcToStore);
}
```

Also, since you recieve a `const T&` in your constructor, you might want to constraint your function to be only callable with what could compile:

```
template<typename T>
using is_valid_foo_function = std::is_convertible<
    BaseT*, // form
    std::tuple_element_t<0, typename function_traits<T>::arguments> // to
>;
```

And use the constraint like that:

```
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<is_valid_foo_function<T>::value>* = nullptr>
Foo(const T& func) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Would this work when I wanted to store the passed functions in a vector?
I'm sorry, there were some mistakes in the original question, as the part where the function gets stored was messed up. I updated this.

Comment: You can store a vector of `std::function`, yet receive `const T&` in the constructor.

Comment: @csk I updated the example to reflect more closely what you did originally.